# <picture>'s srcset attribute getting overriden by WordPress or PHP after update

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a site with custom HTML code that looks a bit like this

```
<picture>
        <source media="(orientation: portrait)" srcset="path-to-imgae" alt="foo">
        <img srcset="path-to-landscape-image" alt="bar">    
</picture>
```

Syntax checks out, runs locally, even worked when first implemented over 5 years ago!

The problem comes after updating PHP or, maybe WordPress itself. To my understanding, it seems to not recognize srcset (or sizes for that matter) as a native `<source>` attribute and prepends them with `data-` to make them more HTML5 compliant I suppose

While I can think of various hacky workarounds, far and away the best solution would be if there was a way to tell the server *stop treating this as a custom attribute*

Comment: PHP 7.4 and WordPress 5.8.1. Should have mentioned that

Comment: Is this HTML in a WYSIWYG editor, or a PHP template file? Do you have any optimization plugins installed?

Comment: It's a raw HTML block in the Gutenberg editor. I don't actually have access to the plugins menu on the live site but, to my understanding, no plugins were installed between it functioning prior to the update and breaking after

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, WordPress doesn’t convert any unknown attribute to a `data-` attribute. It is possible this is a Gutenberg-specific thing, but that seems unlikely, too.